# Getting last item in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the last item in a array using JavaScript. 
But I'm always getting all items in the array.

So far, I've tried several methods. Here is my code:

```js
 var pathCoords = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
        
 var sample1 = pathCoords[pathCoords.length -1];
        
 var sample2 = pathCoords.slice(-1)[0];
 
 console.log(sample1, sample2);
```

Comment: sample does contain the last element of the array. Isn't that what you want

Comment: Hi, i tried that method but i always get all items inside the array instead of getting only the 5 the last item in a array

Comment: Define "getting" because all I can think of is you're logging `pathCoords` instead of `sample`.

Comment: pathCoords is the var where i have a array
var sample,here is the method where i will get the last item in pathCoords

Comment: If you add `console.log("pathCoords: ", pathCoords);` and
`console.log("sample: ", sample);` you should find your sample code is working, if not, then, it's broken not because of the code you've shown us.

Comment: I've turned your sample code into a snippet (you could have done that too). Please run it and check out the results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last item in an array](//stackoverflow.com/q/3216013/90527)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can use splice method of array like this :

**var sample = pathCoords.splice(pathCoords.length-1);**

Comment: This will mutate the array, which the OP is not likely to want. Also, it returns an array containing the last element as the only value, not the last value itself.